# How can Alexa recognize Stop/Cancel intent whe in ElicitSlot mode

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have an alexa skill and I'm using **Dialog Management** for **dynamically elicit slot**.
For example I have one Intent that called **OrderIntent** with 3 slots: drink, coffeRoast, teaType.

When a user asks for a drink for example coffee, I'm using **ELICITSLOT** to stay in **OrderIntent** and asking the user for the coffee roast or tea type.

It works great.
The problem is that when I'm waiting for the second answer from user (tea type/ coffee roast) 
Alexa doesn't recognize other intents like **AMAZON.StopIntent** or **AMAZON.CancelIntent**
So when Alexa waits for the tea type/ coffee roast and the user say "stop" I get in my code the value "stop" for "teatype" instead of invoking the AMAZON.StopIntent and stop the session.

Is there any solution for that in Alexa? to use the **ELICITSLOT** option and still recognize the other intents?

Thanks!

Comment: I used this tutorial to create my skill: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/dbceb5dd-3c4d-40f1-be22-172f4050fbcb/building-conversational-alexa-skills-how-to-dynamically-elicit-slots-based-on-a-previous-answer-using-dialog-management

Answer (score 0):

It unfortunately does not look like it works. I tried re-ordering the handlers so that CancelIntent comes first in my handler, but because the ElicitSlot mode is tied to the intent name with said slot, the CancelIntent "canHandle" function will never trigger.

Your best bet is to make a function that takes in a slot value and returns if that slot value is possibly a cancel command. You'll also need to come up with your own cancel key words, since Amazon does not officially document all of their "cancel" trigger words.

```
export const isCancelCommand = (slotValue: string) =>
    [
        'stop',
        'end',
        'cancel',
        'quit',
        'exit',
        'enough',
        'pause',
        'halt',
        'abort',
        'forget it',
        'cease',
        'never mind',
    ].includes(slotValue.toLowerCase());
```